# Random censoring threshold

Tags: regression, random-variable, censoring, threshold

I am trying to estimate the following censored model: $y_{it}=\beta X_{it} + \epsilon_{it}$.

I only observe $y_{it}$ if $y_{it}\leq z_{it}$, otherwise $y_{it}=z_{it}$. The trick is that $z_{it}$ itself is random, and comes from some distribution $f\left(\cdot\right)$.

I think standard Tobit models do not apply since the threshold is random. Does this correspond to any standard model/application/package in R? Any non-parametric ideas are also welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of any R implementations, but the model you're looking for is [Nelson (1977)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0304-4076(77)90003-3).